# Custom object in a header field in Spring MockMvc

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm writing integration test for a REST API in Spring and I need to pass a custom header. Currently I'm doing something like this:

```
mockMvc.perform(get("/something")
    .header("header", header.toHeaderString())
```

Where object is a custom object containing all the data I want to pass in the header and toHeaderString is a method that serializes this data to a String in a specific format. This is a) quite ugly and b) frequent source of annoying errors, when I forget to call toHeaderString.

Is there a way to tell Spring to do this conversion automatically? Like this:

```
mockMvc.perform(get("/something")
    .header("header", header)
```

Conversion the other way (in the Controller) is done automatically, because the class has a constructor which accepts a single String argument.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/something", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public Collection<Something> getSomething(
    @RequestHeader("header") MyHeader header)
```

EDIT:

So I figured out that it works if I do the conversion in MyHeader.toString. This way, however, I loose the ability to log the object in a human readable form. It would be nice if I could retain toString for debugging purposes, so I'm leaving the question open.

Comment: can you show MyHeader class